# Is there an API to ArcGIS Online's My Content listing?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-platform

This question pertains to ArcGIS Online, aka ArcGIS.com, aka ArcGIS for Organizations.

If I log into ArcGIS.com then choose My Content, I can choose > Layers > Features to see the feature layers available to my account.

[image]

Is it possible to get to this listing programatically, eg via a REST API to ArcGIS.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
You can work with the REST Api.
This is the link for the ESRI [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Working_with_users_groups_and_items/02r3000000mt000000/).

Comment: Thanks. I find it really hard to search for stuff regarding ArcGIS online, since Esri keep changing how they refer to it.